# UWP Deploy app remotely

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Is it possible to build a `Universal Windows Application` for platform `ARM` and deploy it remotely, without cable connection? Like Android app, that have file `applicationname.apk` that you can send via internet, download to SD card and install from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can sideload apps, and also update/deploy it through the Store. Those are your options basically.

For sideloading, you can only do this to developer-enabled phones:

https://frayxrulez.wordpress.com/2015/06/18/how-to-sideload-uwp-apps-to-windows-10-mobile/